# Java - connection always resets when sending data from client to server

Tags: java, network-programming

I don't know what's wrong with the code as it always resets the connection when I send an input from Client to Server. The error report indicates problem on `get.readLine()` on Client code.

This is the code on Client Side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Client
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    String hostName = "localhost";
    Socket client = null;

    try{
        client = new Socket(hostName, 9972);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Host unknown. Cannot establish connection");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot establish connection. Server may not be up." + e.getMessage());
    }

    PrintWriter send = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader get = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a 7-bits binary to send: ");
    String input;

    while((input = read.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String codeWord = addParity(input);
        send.println(codeWord);
        System.out.println("Server responds: " + get.readLine());
    }

    send.close();
    get.close();
    read.close();
    client.close();
}

public static String addParity(String data)
{
    //Some code block here
}
}
```

This is the code on Server Side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int port = 9972;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    PrintWriter send = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader get = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    String input;
    while((input = get.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(input.length() == 11 && input.matches("[01]+"))
        {
            String data = "";

            Random rand = new Random();
            int change = rand.nextInt(1);
            for(int I = 0; I < change; i++)
            {
                data = modify(input);
            }
            String result = HammingCheck(data);

            send.println(result);
        }
        else
            send.println("Input is invalid. Echo: " + input);

        if(input.equals("bye"))
            break;
    }

    send.close();
    get.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}

public static String modify(String input)
{
    //Some code to modify the string
}

public static String HammingCheck(String data)
{
    //Some code to perform hamming code checking
}

public static String removeParity(String data)
{
    //some code to remove parity bits
}
}
```

This is the error report:

```
Attempting to connect to server at host: localhost
Connection established.
Enter a 7-bits binary string as message to server: 1111111
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at ClientSide.Client.main(Client.java:35)
```

Comment: You open the server first before the client right?  Does your IDE (or whatever you are working in) support running multiple projects at once?

Comment: Just tested your code and it works.  I removed the parts where you have the `Random` and modify the string, but kept the sending back part, and it works.  There must be something else in your parity system, or a firewall that is preventing you from sending data.  I'm leaning toward firewall.  If you have Avast as an anti-virus, I know that it disables Java programs from running, and that may be what you are running into.

Comment: @Gilderman It would prevent the connection. The connection is established here.

Comment: In this project, I extended another similar project that uses Hamming Code to correct 1 error, and this one is working on at least 1 error. The "another project" was running well with the same hostname and port. So I am so confused of those problems on this code.

Comment: @EJP  Ah, okay, I don't have Avast, and therefore can't test it (just what I've found from distributing some of my projects).

Comment: @JayNg.  Well, I don't really know what to say.  I tested this using Java Monkey Engine as my IDE, and ran this on Mac OS 10.10, and everything worked perfectly (aside from the bits I commented out with the parity, as you didn't provide them).  Maybe your parity code is changing something with the string that resets the connection?  Try removing your parity code method (just comment out `String codeWord = addParity(input);` in the client, and put `input` instead of `codeWord` in the line below it).  Maybe that will work, or at least narrow it down.

Comment: thank you very much! Gliderman.. I will try it ;)